# Setting Column Visibility in AgGrid React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a BE that returns an Array of objects (columns) in React. The objects are structured like this {headerName: 'string', field: 'string', visible: boolean}. The visible parameter doesn't actually do anything as the column will always be visible. I know in AgGrid the Column Object has a visible parameter which if changed shows or hides the column. How can I make AgGrid use the visible parameter the backend gives me? Am I using the wrong strategy here? How would you do it? As far as changing the object returned by the backend and AgGrid settings.

Answer (score 0):

To hide/show a column in AG Grid, you have to set the `hide` property on the column: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-display-hide

[image]

Since your server is returning `visibility`, I would suggest either of the two approaches:

1. On the client side - Add a function to modify the data returned from the server, such that `visibility` is renamed to `hide`

2. On the server side - the response object for the data should have the `hide` property

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I can't modify the value of hide, it says it is a read-only value , how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce that in my end without an example, but if you are trying to update the columns after they've been initially set, you'd have to use Column State to update them: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-state/

Answer (score 0):

use `useMemo` and recreate the columnDefs when needed:

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-hide-column-7u424t?file=/src/App.js)